# JMeter and Live User Monitoring

Tags: logging, server, jmeter, monitoring

I have a requirements to monitor real time Live users using JMeter. The platform itself consists of many components Rest, Soap, Business java, backend oracle .... My requirement is to monitor specific functionality in different layers:

- Rest https://myApp/search/employee/55
- **SOAP Web method for search employee** (important)
- Oracle procedure for search employee

We don’t need real time graphical plots, but just a log file with the necessary information like response time, ...

Do you think this is achievable by JMeter?

- If yes, could you please provide some links or tutorials?
- If No, what are the free alternatives?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think JMeter is the best choice as its main functionality is **simulating the live users**, not monitoring them. I would recommend considering an [APM (application performance management) tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management), there are some free and open source options like:

- [PinPoint](https://github.com/naver/pinpoint)
- [inspectIT](http://www.inspectit.rocks/)
- [Scouter](https://github.com/scouter-project/scouter)

Theoretically you can use JMeter for monitoring as well, per se it doesn't offer much, however if you install [PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) you will be able to collect and plot [70+ metrics](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md#supported-metrics)

See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for more details if needed

Answer (score 0):

With Jmeter you generate expected traffic and capture response time, error rate etc at client side. Where for server level monitoring you can go for opensource APM like glowroot which I personally prefer for Java applications.. :). It's easy, fast to set up.
Ref: https://demo.glowroot.org/transaction/average?transaction-type=Web
I hope this will help you.